# Spring Web Flow with JSF 2 - h:commandButton not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I'm currently using Java Server Faces (Mojarra 2.1.7) and Spring(3.1.0.RELEASE)/Spring-Webflow(2.3.1.RELEASE). My webapplication is inspired by the [Spring-Primefaces-Showcase](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/webflow-primefaces-showcase/).
Everything is working fine besides the fact, that I can't call a method from a `h:commandButton` element. Some example code (flow &  view definition) :

view.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText id="hello" value="${someBean.hello}"/>
  <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="execTest" />
</h:form>
```

flow.xml:

```
<var name="someBean" class="some.packagename.SomeBean"/>

<view-state id="view">
  <on-render>
    <evaluate expression="someBean.test()" />
  </on-render>
  <transition on="execTest">
    <evaluate expression="someBean.test()" />
  </transition>
</view-state>
```

This results in a InputField, filled with the correct corresponding value of `someBean.hello` (which is simply a String "hello") and one single execution of `someBean.test()` (just prints "test" to system.out). The button is also created,
showing the correct text "Submit", but with no execution of `someBean.test()` being called when the user clicks on it.
Obviously the problem has nothing to do with the Bean because the expression gets correctly executed when rendering the page.
What can cause this kind of error?
Any help would be appreciated!

Regards,
jeyp

Some of my configs for completeness :
(Spring-Security has no access restrictions atm)

spring-webflow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

  <!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
  <flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <flow-execution-listeners>
      <listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
      <listener ref="securityListener"/>
    </flow-execution-listeners>
  </flow-executor>

  <!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
  <flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
     <flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
  </flow-registry>

  <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
  <faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" development="true" />

  <!-- A listener to create and release a FacesContext -->
  <beans:bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>

  <!-- A listener to apply Spring Security authorities -->
  <beans:bean id="securityListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener" />

</beans:beans>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
  xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="spring-webflow.xml" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Scan for Spring beans declared via annotations. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="some.basepackage" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** and /css/** by efficiently 
    serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/... directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

    <!-- 
    Enable processing of JSF 2 resource requests. For example:
    /webflow-primefaces-showcase/app/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces
  -->
  <faces:resources  />


  <!--
    Maps request paths to flows in the flowRegistry; e.g. a path of
    /hotels/booking looks for a flow with id "hotels/booking"
  -->
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
  </beans:bean>

    <!-- 
     Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .xhtml resources 
     in the /WEB-INF/views directory 
     -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </beans:bean>

  <!--
    Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations
  -->
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
  </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <!-- 
    SPRING ROOT WEB APPLICATION CONTEXT
  -->

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- 
    SPRING SECURITY
  -->

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

   <filter>
     <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>


  <!-- 
    JSF 2 IMPLEMENTATION
  -->

  <!-- Use JSF view templates saved as *.xhtml, for use with Facelets -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Enables special Facelets debug output during development -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
      <param-value>1</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at runtime -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- 
    SPRING MVC
  -->

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 
      Spring Security Facelets tag library declaration 
    -->
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring_security.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <!-- 
    DEFAULT PAGE
  -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  

</web-app>
```

root-context.xml and spring-security.xml do not contain important definitions
for this case.